# How dangerous is tossing equipment off the ISS?

Tags: iss, reentry, debris, very-low-earth-orbit

On 2023 June 22, during an ISS spacewalk, Sergey Prokopyev and Dmitry Petelin ["tossed overboard"](https://www.space.com/iss-spacewalk-russian-equipment-jettison-june-2023) three no longer needed devices, "off the back of the space station in a direction that ensured that the gear could never make recontact with the outpost" before burning up in the atmosphere.

At that time, the ISS was about 400 km above ground.  Below it are quite a few other [satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_low_Earth_orbit), and quite a lot of tracked debris.  What is the risk of these three new pieces of litter hitting something before burning up, thereby possibly damaging a satellite or further scattering orbital debris?  Why didn't they instead retrieve the devices, to be loaded onto the next "garbage truck" whose departing trajectory could and would be controlled?

Comment: Any debris or satellite below 300 km would reenter in about 6 month anyway.

Comment: The wikipedia article on VLEO mentions several satellites that low which orbited for  years.  Debris, on the other hand, tends not to have propellant to prolong its life.

Comment: different but related: [Was this large pieces of "space junk" just released from the ISS in the "nadir and retrograde" direction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24749/12102) and [This ISS trash deployment looks more like 2 feet than 2 inches per second, was it too fast or are these articles incorrect?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50717/12102) but yours is the first question (I'm aware of) that elicited such an informative answer about the bureaucratic procedure. Of course there is little control over the speed and direction, so it's not like they do any detailed trajectory risk calc.

Comment: See also [Are the cubesats deployed from the ISS always directed "nadir and retrograde"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29531/12102) and this answer: [If you launch nadir and retrograde, you will put the object into a lower energy orbit such that, barring ISS deboosts (they do happen, but they are rare), it will never again intersect ISS's orbit... These objects are also large enough that they can be independently tracked once they've gained enough separation from ISS, so any unlikely potential recontact scenario can be averted.](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22746/12102)

Comment: My take on that is again that there can't be a detailed calculation that it won't hit anything, just that the thing should be *trackable* so if it does start looking like there will be a conjunction ([1](https://celestrak.org/SOCRATES/), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunction)) they can send a signal to the *other satellite* to "Get out of the way!"

Comment: @uhoh I believe you are correct in the previous comment. There's nothing in the Directive explicitly about conjunctions with other satellites, just the trackability requirement. Most of the trajectory stuff in the Directive is about not hitting the ISS itself.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can imagine that some large and/or complex items really need careful study to understand the risk of premature breakup. For example how to secure a 2.9 ton pallet of batteries (and other items?) ([1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50718/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61489/12102)) was probably studied at length - wouldn't want the possibility of a micrometeorite hitting a single strap to initiate [rapid unscheduled disassembly](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10022/12102)

Comment: "wikipedia article on VLEO mentions several satellites that low which orbited for years" that is only possible using orbit raising by propulsion.

Comment: Yes.  But propellant doesn't make a satellite invulnerable to getting hit by litter, if the litter isn't tracked.  (Before O.M's answer, I didn't know that trackability was required.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*tl;dr It's not dangerous or they don't do it.*

As you might expect, this gets studied to death before it happens.

> Anything planned to be jettisoned or deployed from the ISS or any ISS Visiting Vehicle must
> show compliance with the various safety requirements documented in ISS Partner Program
> Directive (PPD) 1011, the ISS Jettison Policy. The ISS Program’s analysis and approval process
> for jettison candidates typically takes roughly 3-6 months, depending on the complexity of the
> jettison candidate.

Some excerpts -

> The Jettison Policy requires all candidates be trackable by the Space Surveillance Network
>
> In addition to trackability, the policy also requires candidates demonstrate they don’t pose a
> significant risk of on-orbit fragmentation.
>
> There are a number of detailed
> requirements in the Jettison Policy dealing with re-contact risk and how it is assessed.

Source: [ISSPO Best Practices for Satellite Payload Developers](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/20190729_satellite_pd_best_practices.pdf)

The Directive is available in its entirety [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20230001348/downloads/PPD_1011_RC_FINAL.pdf). The rest of the answer comes from there.

Why don't they retrieve the devices? The following items are candidates for jettison.

> 1. Items that pose a safety issue for the ISS or for return onboard an ISS Visiting
>    Vehicle (contamination, materials degradation, etc.).
> 2. Items that negatively impact ISS utilization, return manifest or on-orbit stowage
>    manifests.
> 3. Items that represent an Extravehicular Activity (EVA) timeline savings large enough
>    to reduce the sum of the risks of EVA exposure time and the orbital environment’s
>    hazardous debris population, compared to the sum of such risks without a jettison.
> 4. Items that are designed for jettison