Has a crewed craft ever exploded during re-entry?
Crewed crafts re-enter the earth's atmosphere at high speeds and hot temperatures. This of course can prove to be highly dangerous to the crew inside. My question is, has this re-entry ever caused crew member deaths or the breaking of certain parts?

what constitutes an "explosion"? Does a desintegration due to thermal or mechanical stresses (like in Starship's answer) fall under that category? Technically it's not an explosion, but it definitely was the incident which caused the shuttle programme to be stopped eventually. RUD is not unheard of before, either. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/who-coined-the-phrase-rapid-unscheduled-disassembly

Yes, according to Encyclopedia Brittanica:

On February 1, 2003, Columbia broke up catastrophically over north-central Texas at an altitude of about 60 km (40 miles) as it was returning from an orbital mission. All seven crew members died, including Ilan Ramon, the first Israeli astronaut to go into space.

